# Why wont -exec run?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am using the below script as a clean up script. The find sections returns the correct results, but for some reason the -exec section doesn't run.

```
find /users/rhysparker/downloads/ -maxdepth 1 -iname \*.pkg -o -iname \*.app -o -iname \*.dmg -exec mv {} /folder/location/ \;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-o` operation has low precedence, so your `-exec` is bound exclusively to the `*.dmg` test. Use parentheses to group the statement properly. (And quote them so the shell passes them through to `find`).

```
find /users/rhysparker/downloads/ -maxdepth 1 \( -iname \*.pkg -o -iname \*.app -o -iname \*.dmg \) -exec mv {} /folder/location/ \;
```

Comment: Alan Strikes again. Thanks for that. I should have thought of that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In `expr1 -o expr2`, if `expr1` is true, the `expr2` will not be evaluated.

In your command:

```
-iname \*.pkg OR
-iname \*.app OR
-iname \*.dmg AND -exec mv {} /folder/location/ \;
```

If one of the first two is true, the last will not be evaluated. So you have to use `()` to change the expr:

```
find /users/rhysparker/downloads/ -maxdepth 1 \( -iname \*.pkg -o -iname \*.app -o -iname \*.dmg \) -exec mv {} /folder/location/ \;
```

Now, it becomes:

```
(-iname \*.pkg OR -iname \*.app OR -iname \*.dmg) AND
-exec mv {} /folder/location/ \;
```

This ensure the `-exec` will be evaluated when the files is found.